# Determining which of these relations are reflexive

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

For my question, please see the attached image (specifically, example 5).

For example 8 (not shown), we're supposed to refer back to example 5 (shown below) and see which of the given relations are reflexive. We can easily see that $R_1$ and $R_4$ are reflexive, as for every a $\in$ R, (a, a) $\in$ R.

I'm more confused by the fact that $R_3$ is also reflexive. Part of the condition makes sense - specifically, $R_3$ = {(a, b) | a = b}. But we also know that $R_3$ = {(a, b) | a = -b}. This means that in addition to containing the pairs (1, 1) and (2, 2), it should contain (1, -1). But there isn't an a $\in$ R such that a = -1.

Is it reflexive because $a = -b \Rightarrow (1) = -(-1) \Rightarrow 1 = 1$, and there is the pair (1, 1) $\in$ R?

Thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: If is enough for the relation to contain all pairs $(a,a)$ for $a\in\mathbb{Z}$ for it to be a reflexive relation in $\mathbb{Z}$. It doesn't matter that it also contains other pairs, like $(a,-a)$ in that example.

Comment: So, we're only concerned with a, not -a?

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense and doesn't follow from anything I said.

Comment: Don't worry about it, I understand. I'll mark as answered if you want to post your reply as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(1,1)$ is in $R$, and so is $(1,-1)$, correct.

For reflexivity, however, we don't care whether or not $(1,-1)$ is in $R$. So, the fact that we have some $(a,b)$ with $a \neq b$ in $R$ does not make $R$ non-reflexive.

Now, we *do* care whether $(-1,-1)$ is in $R$, but it is: for $a = -1$, you can pick $b=-1$.

And indeed, for any integer $a$, we can pick $b=a$, and so you have $(a,a)$ in $R$.  This is why $R$ is reflexive.